# Focus Google Maps after adding Multiple points

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Center map and zoom to fit the markers on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002424/center-map-and-zoom-to-fit-the-markers-on-the-screen)

I'm just writing an app that uses Google Maps.  The app adds multiple points to a map.  I would like to be able to focus the map on these multiple points after they've been added, but don't know how.

So far, my inclination is to do the following:

1. When adding points, keep track of min longitude, max longitude, min latitude, max latitude
2. Calculate avg longitude, avg latitude

So.. Now I would know how to find my map center.

**Does anyone know how I would calculate the zoom?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the locations to an empty [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object.

Call [google.maps.Map.fitBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) on the resulting bounds.

psuedo code (not tested, assumes your markers are in an array in scope named gmarkers, assumes your google.maps.Map object is called "map"):

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) 
{
   bounds.extend(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: thanks!  I'm assuming that I would set LatLngBounds as the min / max lat / lng (maybe + a little buffer)?   Cheers!

Comment: Actually if you create an empty bounds object, add all your markers to it with bounds.extend(marker.getPosition()) and just call map.fitBounds(bounds), it works pretty well.

Comment: thx homie!! this helped tonnes

Answer (score 0):

If you know points(markers) in advance than set the point which is center of all as setCenter marker point and rest as markers and set Zoomlevel

If you don't know points in advance and know the location ( e.g. particular state or county or region) than get center point of it get the lat/lng of it and set that point as setCenter marker point, set zoomlevel accordingly and add markers (points).